# How can I read a specific key in c# being anywhere in the program. c#

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner programer that have started programming a week ago. As part of the learning to consolidate knowledge, I try to recreate my Toothbrush program. I want to dependent the program on two keys **PowerButton** and **OptionButton**.
Here's the code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
int powerButtonCount = 0;

int optionButtonCount = 0;



if (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar == 'p')
{
    powerButtonCount++;
    while (powerButtonCount >= 1)
    {
        if (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar == 'o')
        {
            optionButtonCount++;
            switch (optionButtonCount)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Sensitive");
                    while (powerButtonCount == 2 && optionButtonCount == 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Brushing in Sensitive mode!");
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Gum Care");
                    while (powerButtonCount == 2 && optionButtonCount == 2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Brushing in Gum Care mode!");
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("Intense");
                    while (powerButtonCount == 2 && optionButtonCount == 3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Brushing in Intense mode!");
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("Daily Clean");
                    while (powerButtonCount == 2 && optionButtonCount == 4)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Brushing in Daily Clean mode!");
                    }
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Console.WriteLine("Whiten");
                    while (powerButtonCount == 2 && optionButtonCount == 5)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Brushing in Whiten mode!");
                    }
                    break;

            }
        }
        else if (powerButtonCount == 3)
        {
            powerButtonCount = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Good Bye!");
        }
    }
}
```

What I came across is problem that I can't read input from user in realtime. After my testing, seems like I'm able to jump between switches, but when I want to initialize "Brushing thing" C# doesn't read 'p'.

Comment: All of the `while` loops in your `switch` structure appear to be infinite loops.  Why?  What is the purpose of that?

Comment: Cause when ideally you brush your teeth, you want to run the brush as long as you need to. I just need to find a way to stop the program after another press of "PowerButton". Idea of program: 1. You press PowerButton to start start the brush. 2. You choose in which option you want to clean your teeth (with another button - OptionButton). 3. You lunch cleaning with PowerButton. 4 You turn off cleaning with PowerButton.

Comment: You might be looking to do multi-threading perhaps?  Where one thread writes output while another waits for input?

Comment: Well it seems as reasonable solution. However I came up with this exercise to practice loops and I thought I could manage to do that only with loops haha. Multi-threading looks kind of advanced for me now.

Comment: Congratulations on getting started. There will be periods of great frustration when stuff won't work or you won't know if you're doing anything right. I hope you push through all of it. We need everyone we can get.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to push through it but I just need a little hand in here haha

Comment: I have to ask… You … _”started programming a week ago.”_ … ? … Do you mean you started a programming class and this is the first assignment? Have you written any programs in the past?

Comment: @JohnG No I haven't. What I mean is that I bought some online course and I learn basics from it. I just try to code examples I come up with to actually get better at it. I thought this would be quite easy and simple to code but it turned out to be a challange for me haha!

Comment: Well… I suggest you go back to your online tutorial on take a closer look at how to control loops. Specifically, how to control `while` loops. StackOverflow is not a tutorial service and an answer to your current question about the currently posted code will be directly related to controlling `while` loops. Example… ALL of the `while` loops in the `switch/case` statements are “infinite” loops and once entered will NEVER leave. Also, the main … `while (powerButtonCount >= 1) { …` loop will never exit. You need to fix that so they will eventually exit.